# Phusion Passenger opens random ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger, passenger-nginx

I'm experiencing same problem as described here [Strange public listening ports in Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518609/strange-public-listening-ports-in-passenger).

Phusion Passenger is randomly opening ports and I have no idea how to further investigate it.

- Passenger Version : 6.0.14
- ruby-2.4.1
- nginx version: nginx/1.20.2
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- Linux 4.15.0-192-generic

```
netstat -lp
tcp        0      0 localhost:45363         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13226/Passenger Rub
tcp        0      0 localhost:34515         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7653/Passenger Ruby
```

```
ps -p 7653 -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
7653 427776 user1    user1    ruby            Passenger RubyApp: /home/user1/apps/application1/current (production)
```

Thank you in advance for any tips how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is by design.  They can be used to manage the associated backend apps in some ways.  See here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/pull/2173 for a discussion.